# Magento2.3.5 Disabled dynamic row system field

Tags: system.xml, magento2.3.5, dynamic-rows

How can one add a disabled attribute to an input field in dynamic row system ref: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/ext-best-practices/tutorials/dynamic-row-system-config.html

What I've tried:

```
$this->addColumn('price', ['label' => __('Price'), 'class' => 'required-entry', 'disabled' => true]);
```

I would think that this would add the attribute disabled with value true. But it doesn't

Anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
        $this->addColumn('price', ['label' => __('Price'), 'style'=>'pointer-events: none; background: #CCC; color: #333; border: 1px solid #666 ']);
```

It's not the answear you need, but it helps.